# How to change the content width using php?

Tags: php, content-width

I've created a custom template using php and would like to know how to modify the content width?
Do I have to create a class within php and then modify the width using CSS?

This is how my php template looks right now:

```
<?php /* Template Name: NewEventTemplate */ ?>

<?php
/**
* The template for displaying pages.
*
* @package Salient WordPress Theme
* @version 10.5
*/

// Exit if accessed directly.
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

get_header();
nectar_page_header( $post->ID );
$nectar_fp_options = nectar_get_full_page_options();
?>  

<div class="container-wrap">
    <div class="<?php if ( $nectar_fp_options['page_full_screen_rows'] !== 'on' ) { echo 'container'; } ?> main-content">
        <div class="row">
            </div>
              <header class="entry-header">
             <?php the_post(); ?>
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
  </header>

            <?php

            nectar_hook_before_content(); 
        the_content();

            if ( have_posts() ) :
                while ( have_posts() ) :
                    the_post(); 
                    the_content();

                endwhile;
            endif;

            nectar_hook_after_content();

            ?>
        </div><!--/row-->
    </div><!--/container-->
</div><!--/container-wrap-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: There's no trick. Just HTML and CSS, like any other webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, often the best way is as you describe. In your template file add something like this:

```
<div class="container-wrap se-366024">
```

Then in your `style.css` (or any other enqueued stylesheet)

```
.se-366024 {
    width:960px;
}
```

If you are wanting to set a max width across the site you may want to look into the `$content_width` global supported by Core and many plugins:

- https://developer.wordpress.com/themes/content-width/
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width